# Spacy, how not to remove "not" when cleaning the text with space

Tags: python, spacy, stop-words

I use this spacy code to later apply it on my text, but i need the negative words to stay in the text like "not".

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") 

def my_tokenizer(sentence): 
    return [token.lemma_ for token in tqdm(nlp(sentence.lower()), leave = False) if token.is_stop == False and token.is_alpha == True and  token.lemma_ ]
```

Whit this when i apply i get this as a result :

```
[hello, earphone, work]
```

However the original sentence was

```
hello,my earphones are still not working.
```

So, i would like to see the following sentence: `[earphone, still, not, work]`
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"not" is actually a stop word and in your code if a token is removed if it's a stopword. You can see this either by looking at the list of Spacy stopwords

```
"not" in spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
```

or by looping over the tokens of your doc object

```
for tok in nlp(text.lower()):
  print(tok.text, tok.is_stop, tok.lemma_)

#hello False hello
#, False ,
#my True my
#earphones False earphone
#are True be
#still True still
#not True not
#working False work
#. False .
```

### Solution

To solve this, you should remove the target words such as "not" from the list of stop_words. You can do it this way:

```
# spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS.remove("not")
# or for multiple words use this
to_del_elements = {"not", "no"}
nlp.Defaults.stop_words = nlp.Defaults.stop_words - to_del_elements
```

Then you can rerun your code and you'll get your expected results:

```
import spacy
#spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS.remove("not")
to_del_elements = {"not", "no"}
nlp.Defaults.stop_words = nlp.Defaults.stop_words - to_del_elements
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") 
def my_tokenizer(sentence): 
    return [token.lemma_ for token in tqdm(nlp(sentence.lower()), leave = False) if token.is_stop == False and token.is_alpha == True and  token.lemma_ ] 

sentence = "hello,my earphones are still not working. no way they will work"
results = my_tokenizer(sentence)
print(results)

#['hello', 'earphone', 'not', 'work', 'no', 'way', 'work']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Where do i exactly put this code nlp.Defaults.stop_words.remove("not")

Comment: @Giorgi I have updated the answer, you can try the code under solution

Comment: @Giorgi if I answered your question please make sure to pick it as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you it works :D , one more question, can i also add "no" and not just "not"

Comment: Yes you can add whatever you want @Giorgi

Comment: Oh i meant like in the same line, like a list or just run them one by one, and thank you for replying ☺️

Comment: I have updated the solution to handle your request @Giorgi :)